# SearchView on RecyclerView no work how to fix?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I implemented a search but when trying to filter nothing happens someone knows some way to make it work correctly, I can't identify where it is wrong. Thanks in advance. any help is welcome.

Below are codes of my activity where is the recycler view. And model contacts.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Contacts Model

```
public class Contacts {
    public String name, status, image;

    public Contacts()
    {

    }

    public Contacts(String name, String status, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

---

My Activity

```
public class FindFriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView FindFriendsRecyclerList;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;

    private SearchView searchView;
    private Query query;

    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ColorSpace.Model> options;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_friends);


        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        FindFriendsRecyclerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_recycler_list);
        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Find Friends");
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.materialSearchPrincipal);


    }




    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
                new Builder<Contacts>()
                        .setQuery(UsersRef, Contacts.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder>(options) {

                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Contacts model)
                    {
                        holder.userName.setText(model.getName());
                        holder.userStatus.setText(model.getStatus());
                        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);


                        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view)
                            {
                                String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(FindFriendsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
                                startActivity(profileIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public FindFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
                    {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                        FindFriendViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            private void fetch(Query query) {

                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
                        new Builder<Contacts>()
                                .setQuery(query, Contacts.class)
                                .build();


            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .child("User").orderByChild("name").equalTo(s);

                if(s.equals("")){
                    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                            .getReference()
                            .child("name");
                }

                fetch(query);

                return false;
            }
        });
        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);


        adapter.startListening();

    }




    public static class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userName, userStatus;
        CircleImageView profileImage;


        public FindFriendViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuPesquisa);


        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new reference to `adapter` in `fetch()` method, because after every search the returned item count is changing. That's why in my example I have done  like this in the `fetch()` method:

```
adapter = new CustomFirebaseRecylerAdapter<Model, CustomFirebaseRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder>(options);
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

try creating a new adapter `instance` in the `fetch()` method and then setting up the following:

```
adapter.startListening();
FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Sorry but I'm not really able to implement :(

Comment: show me your complete code. where are you having problem ?

Comment: Hi i m change  after fetch(query); new adpater adaptertest1.startListening();
                FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adaptertest1); in app search no work :/ this full code  https://pastebin.com/ChjJ1VaY

Comment: Thanks for your patience. and sorry for the disturb. I can't instantiate a new adapter so I just duplicate adapter and switched to = adaptertest1. I must be doing something very wrong.

Comment: Please check try to follow this https://pastebin.com/HchUV5N7 this is working for me